# Jinja2 - pass variable to render

Tags: python, jinja2

I'm trying to define a variable named "body" and then pass it to the render statement for a Jinja2 template. If I define the variable on a separate line and then use the render statement with just the variable name, I get an error.

Example code:

```
from jinja2 import Environment, FileSystemLoader
import os

THIS_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))

env = Environment(loader=FileSystemLoader(THIS_DIR),
                         trim_blocks=True)
template =  env.get_template('test_template.html')
body = "test"
html_str = template.render(body)
```

Error for the above code:

```
ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 1; 2 is required
```

It works if I define the variable within the parenthesis of the render statement.

This works but it isn't what I want to do:

```
from jinja2 import Environment, FileSystemLoader
import os

THIS_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))

env = Environment(loader=FileSystemLoader(THIS_DIR),
                         trim_blocks=True)
template =  env.get_template('test_template.html')
html_str = template.render(body="test")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use

```
body = {"body":"test"}
html_str = template.render(body)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
html_str = template(body=body)
```

The `body`left to the equal sign is the name of the variable as it will be called inside the template. The `body`on the right of the equal sign is the name of the variable inside the python code